# Command to increase CPU utilization in my Amazon Linux AMI

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, command-line-interface, autoscaling, amazon-linux

I am learning auto-scaling as a part of my AWS class and running an Amazon Linux instance and I want to increase the CPU utilization so that my auto-scaling policy will launch a new instance. What is the Linux command to increase process utilization of my current running instance? I am a new in Linux CLI.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: I am asking a question about linux command it comes under development.

Comment: As worded there is no intersection with programming or development. [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) are the sites that help with commands. You can flag the question and ask the moderators move it so you don't have to delete it on one site and create it on another site. It also resets the question's score. For whatever reasons, the Stack Exchange network does not allow you to migrate it yourself. Also see [Author initiated migration to other SE sites?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254851)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can...

- Write a python script that uses multiprocessing with an infinite loop to simulate CPU load.
- use linux [`stress`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/stress)
- You can fake it. select your `autoscaling group` > `scaling policies` tab > `actions` button > `execute`